# Spring Boot and Spring Security Keyclock Integration - Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:8180

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I am doing Spring Cloud microservices development using link here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LaZGedpfAyM&t=1279s and I was able to successfully make the GET request but for POST request I am getting the below error.

Source Code link - https://github.com/SaiUpadhyayula/springboot-microservices-project

I am not able to investigate as it seems as it seems issue at Keyclock?

CURL request -

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/order' \
--header 'content-type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJwYkNvVGtKOE0tZmZLaXJ0OXRVRjFNSlFxVUJlaXA3YlJFVzY3akpBMmEwIn0.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.DOeBxnCkL2jUuK_waq5JtOS-a3AD1y3C_hhirpA7lOU8xpgUujsXpjz3o53TJCAHHlxzC42wQ5oeFi6YXiSuuBRP9vpL6ePWYF3PtD2dgpZdkt5QT0BQiSjStGMY7xb4O8sd3BdRL_RkCpRx0GiV_rE4qZcQBHqdkarozOoq23GmbFD0XT5C119EUVjwn2ZirmPzFWYODJp6H5ExDEV1xm6cdZXBJZGSM4tINNaZheV9AkkpFpySt_CD74Hbj0KwbjJMCSGB5hNA0ZLEozjV14FinJrEUlcW8hBogY2Rd-XPqb0lwAlkqdLQKqu0AMWZrl0AoM7YaasZHvB7uZHG2Q' \
--header 'Cookie: SESSION=9328910f-b82e-4fc9-9019-8ae9259aef8e' \
--data-raw '{
    "orderLineItemsList" : [
        {
            "skuCode" : "iPhone 12",
            "price": 1230,
            "quantity" : 1
        }
    ]
}'
```

[image]

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I'm also facing same problem.

Comment: @Rashed - Nope, I think we can connect to owner of repo and seek some help. You can gave reference of this stack link to him